# DateTime Now in a specified timezone

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

How can something like this be implemented in C#:

```
string timeZone = "Fiji Time";
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone);
DateTime dateTimeNowInFiji = new DateTime(timeZoneInfo).Now;
```

Comment: there's a method called TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
var t = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"));
```

NB. To make this work I needed to change "Fiji Time" to "Fiji Standard Time" for the TimeZone id.

Answer (score 0):

C#:

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Fiji Standard Time");
DateTime dateTimeNowInTargetTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, timeZoneInfo);
```